# Renaming github repo loses stars?

Tags: github

Will the stars on the github repo is lost on renaming the project?

Answer (score 1):

No, stars will not be lost if you rename a repository.

From GitHub on [renaming a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/):

> When you rename a repository, all existing information, with the exception of Project Pages URLs, is automatically redirected to the new name, including: Issues, Wikis, **Stars**, Followers